# Need to stop/start components in /etc/init.d

Tags: linux, unix

I want to practice in Linux and specifically starting/stop processes/services from `/etc/init.d`
What processes/services can I stop/start without worrying that my system will become in bad state?

Update for comment of @terdon: `ls /etc/init.d` gives me the following

```
.depend.boot         autofs             boot.device-mapper  boot.md          earlysyslog   kbd               openwsmand     rc2.d           sfcb             xdm  
.depend.halt         autoyast           boot.dmraid         boot.multipath   fbset         kexec             pcscd          rc3.d           single           xfs  
.depend.start        boot               boot.fuse           boot.proc        gpm           mcelog            pm-profiler    rc4.d           skeleton         xinetd  
.depend.stop         boot.apparmor      boot.ipconfig       boot.quota       haldaemon     mdadmd            postfix        rc5.d           skeleton.compat  ypbind  
README               boot.cgroup        boot.kdump          boot.rootfsck    halt          microcode.ctl     powerd         rc6.d           slpd  
SuSEfirewall2_init   boot.cleanup       boot.klog           boot.scpm        halt.local    multipathd        powerfail      rcS.d           smartd  
SuSEfirewall2_setup  boot.clock         boot.ldconfig       boot.swap        haveged       network           puppet         reboot          smb  
aaeventd             boot.compliance    boot.loadmodules    boot.sysctl      inputattach   network-remotefs  purge-kernels  rpasswdd        smbfs  
acpid                boot.crypto        boot.local          boot.udev        ipmi          nfs               random         rpcbind         splash  
alsasound            boot.crypto-early  boot.localfs        boot.udev_retry  ipmievd       nmb               raw            rpmconfigcheck  splash_early  
arpd                 boot.cycle         boot.localnet       cron             irq_balancer  nscd              rc             rsyncd          sshd  
atd                  boot.d             boot.lvm            cups             ivman         ntp               rc0.d          saslauthd       syslog  
auditd               boot.debugfs       boot.lvm_monitor    dbus             joystick      openct            rc1.d          setserial       uuidd
```

Comment: `/etc/init.d/cron`, just don't play with it for too long and don't forget to leave it running when you're done.

Comment: Why don't you post the output of `ls /etc/init.d`? Then we can tell you exactly.

Comment: @terdon:Ok.Updated OP

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have it installed, `httpd` (or `apache2`, depending on your distro) is a good one, since when you practice `start` and `stop`, you can see the results in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a virtual machine application such as VirtualBox will allow you (assuming your computer has sufficient spare resources) to create a clean copy of Linux.

Take a copy of that VM so that you can easily get back to it no matter what you do to the working copy.

Then you can mess around to your hearts content on the VM.

You could also do this with a free or low cost Virtual Private Server (VPS) on the Internet.